# Im I ruining genre recognition when I deconstructed supernatural creatures to be Mutants I.E. X men?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, answers, worldbuilding-process

Deconstruction is a terrible word to use here. But the only word I can think of to describe my world.

But anyway genre recognition is when the audience can understand what genre a movie or tv show falls under.

For example, if you are watching a movie about Ninjas. That movie probably falls under the Ninja/Kung Fu genre. You probably not expecting Cyborgs and Transhumans to come out of nowhere. Because the movie is about Ninja Stuff. Not Transhumanism. You can understand what genre the movie is. Because the movie already established what genre this world falls under.

Can genre recognition be a problem for my world?

.

It's all based on the Gods were space Aliens this whole time concept. They came to earth with their advanced technology that was indistinguishable from Magic. And the humans worship them as Gods. So the Aliens were no different from USA soldiers who were worshipped by tribes. All those religions that worship Aliens were cargo cults this whole time.

Now change the analogy. And replace Aliens with Mutants. A subhuman species of human that have genetic mutations that gift them superpowers. With some not looking like humans too. The Mutants automatically become indistinguishable from Supernatural Creatures.

Supernatural Creatures like Vampires, Werewolves, Skin Walkers, Wendigo, Dragons, etc throughout history were just Humans with genetic mutations that were records of Ancient Mutants walking the earth a long time ago. Causing the muggles/normal humans to make myths and legends about them.

Again does this ruin genre recognition? Supernatural creatures are usually fantasy-based in fiction. And Mutants are usually Science Fiction. The audience is expecting a story about SCI Fi Mutants. Usually expecting a Superhero story since Mutants are usually associated with Superheroes. Then out of nowhere Supernatural Creatures like Vampires and Werewolves show up.

.

I wanted to make a sandbox kitchen sink world like Marvel and DC. Where different multiple beings and different magic systems all coexist in one world.

But then I realized there were more similarities between fictional beings/systems than differences. And when there were differences. The differences were either arbitrary depending on the Writer or so manner I can explain the differences away with simple fan headcanons easily.

There aren't that many differences between Mutants and Wizards/Witches. Yae you can say mutants are born with their powers. And Magic-Users like Wizards and Witches have to learn their powers. But again the difference is so arbitrary that it depends on whatever the Writer wants for the story. In some worlds hell, most worlds the Wizards and Witches are born with powers just like Mutants.

It's a popular opinion for most Writers to prefer to make Magic a biological or innate ability. To make the Wizards or Witches feel more special. And also there is this huge world-building issue that rears its ugly head when you make Magic is learned ability anybody can do. I think most writers are trying to avoid that issue lol.

.

Then the question of "What makes a Magic-User a none mutant?" Comes up. Like if a magic-user has to learn their powers. While the mutant is born with powers. Then what power a magic-user is going to have that is different from a mutant? In fiction, both Mutants and Magic-Users overlap in powers. Physic powers like telekinesis and telepathy are common superpowers shared by both Superheroes and Wizards. Is the difference really that big when both beings can share the same powers? Again the difference is so arbitrary and manner. That it feels like I can replace them so easily. The only thing stopping me is genre recognition lol.

But you also have to understand the nature of mutant superpowers. Their powers are so broad and unique to the individual. That each mutant has their own magic system. Mutants can range from a guy with 8 arms to a woman who can reality warp. Honestly, there is no ceiling with mutant powers. A Wizard/Witch would just be one mutant out of millions of mutants. Magic can be one mutant power out of millions of mutant powers.

,    ..

Cosmic Beings

Extradimensional beings

Aliens

Mutants

And these four beings pretty much cover 98 percent of the broad fictional beings in most fiction.

I guessed it comes down to genre recognition vs arbitrary and manner differences.

Comment: _"So the Aliens were no different from USA soldiers who were worshipped by tribes."_ Wohohoho... I don't know what time period you're talking about, but neither [native american tribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Indian_War), nor [middle-east countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Afghanistan), nor [asian countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_War) were particularly "happy" to have met US soldiers. Whatever the cause was, a lot of people died there on both sides. And it so almost always happen when foreign soldiers come in another country.

Comment: I'm talking about an African Tribe that thought USA soldiers were Gods during world war 2. They even build statues of the USA soldiers.

Comment: Really? Then just know that it is not the most famous story, so expect people to react if you don't explain a little the context.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (a) it isn't a question about the culture, operation, or rules of the Worldbuilding Stack (so it doesn't belong on Meta) and (b) it isn't a question about Worldbuilding (so it doesn't belong on Main). This is a question about nature of writing and belongs on [writing.se].

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that **no, genre recognition won't be ruined by creating such a world or scenario within a world**. In fact, quite the opposite. People are smart. They'll easily create a new genre to fit the altered world they are experiencing.

> For example, if you are watching a movie about Ninjas. That movie probably falls under the Ninja/Kung Fu genre. You probably not expecting Cyborgs and Transhumans to come out of nowhere. Because the movie is about Ninja Stuff. Not Transhumanism. You can understand what genre the movie is. Because the movie already established what genre this world falls under. Can genre recognition be a problem for my world?

What would most likely happen in this instance is that the viewer would initially be led down the garden path by expecting and adjusting to a movie about ninjas. If she's familiar with the genre, she'll slip right into the groove without any problems! She might even wonder if Jackie Chan (or insert your favourite martial arts actor here) will make an appearance.

Once the Cyborgs, Roboborgs, Transborgs, Cylons and actual Swedes start making their appearances, your viewer will experience a momentary dissociation. A "where the heck did théy come from!?!?" moment. Once it's clear that the Ninjaborgs belong in the story the viewer will automatically correct her perception of the world to include Nanoborgs. She will then (probably subconsciously because, you know, epic action packed battle scenes galore!) construct  a novel genre for the movie to fit in and then she'll either sit back and enjoy the Sci-Kung-Fiborg move or else toss it because she hates sci-fi, Borgs and anyone from anywhere near Borg.

The situation you're trying to obtain is the same as the popular mash-up genre books and movies. [*Pride and Prejudice and Zombies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pride_and_Prejudice_and_Zombies) kind of thing.